# Screen-size dependend values for data-x in impress.js

Tags: javascript, css, impress.js

Say one has the following [`impress.js`](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/) code:

```
<div id="title" class="step" data-x="0" data-y="0" data-scale="5">
Foo
</div>
<div id="toc" class="step" data-x="10000" data-y="0" data-scale="1">
bar
</div>
```

This renders fine on a `1920x1080` screen, because `5` (`data-scale`) times `2000` (screen width with some buffer) is `10000`.

But:

- It doesn't render nice on smaller screens (because `1920` is large compared to for instance `800`); and
- For larger screens, the slides can still overlap.

How can one set the slide location, based on the viewport size? Thus something like `500vw`? (tried that, but that didn't work).